# Movement listener in Android

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors

Is it possible to trigger my code with the detection of movement of the phone, while in sleep (i.e., not affecting battery performance)?

Example: My phone is on my desk. I put it in my pocket. My app detects the movement and sends a message through wi-fi to my computer.

Comment: What have you tried? You even have a tag for `accelerometer`. Did you look into that?

Comment: My question isnt if it is possible - i know it is possible and i am able to do it; i want to know if it requires constant wake.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Accelerometer, that you can detect your phones' movement. [Here is an example](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-the-accelerometer-on-android--mobile-22125) BUT must maintain the lifecycle of your application while you use the hardware/sensor component.